# Unable to hide/unhide the SKSpriteNode

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm having trouble with hiding and displaying the `SKSpriteNode`.
However, I'm sure that using `hidden = true` will hide the visibility. What I want to do is to  show the image button when a title is pressed and hide the image button when somewhere else other than the title is pressed. I have the sample code below. I would love to hear from you.

```
startSprite.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width * 0.5, y: self.size.height * 0.5+startSprite.size.height)
self.addChild(startSprite)
startSprite.zPosition = 3
startSprite.hidden = true
startSprite.name = "start"


//When the title is pressed show the startSprite
//clicking a image
if touchNode.name == "normal" {
    startSprite.hidden = false
    if touchNode.name == "start" {
    //start the game when the startSprite is pressed
    } else {
        startSprite.hidden = true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I catch what you mean, you want to show `startSprite` when a title is pressed (whose `name` is `normal`, and hide `startSprite` when other place except the title is pressed. I suggest you give every node a `name` before adding it to the scene. In this way, it is easier to tell which thing you've touched. Hope this will help:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {        
    for touch in touches {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        let touchNode = self.nodeAtPoint(location)

        if touchNode.name == "normal" {
            startSprite.hidden = false
        } else {
            startSprite.hidden = true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you ! It did help.